# How do I run code before calling the primary constructor?

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a class that contains two immutable values, which are set in the primary constructor. I would like to add a secondary constructor that takes a string and parses it to get those two values. However, I can't figure out a way to implement this in Kotlin, as the secondary constructor calls the primary constructor immediately, before parsing the string.

In java, I would call `this(a,b)` in one of the other constructors, but Java doesn't have primary constructors. How do I add this functionality?

```
class Object (a: double, b:double)
{
  val a = a
  val b = b
  constructor(str: String) //Parsing constructor
  {
    //Do parsing
    a = parsed_a
    b = parsed_b
  }
}
```

Comment: You're almost there. `constructor(str: String): this(parseFn(str).a, parseFn(str).b)` will work, assuming parseFn returns a class with a and b accessors.

Comment: I don't think your can have a code block in a secondary constructor

Comment: @user1713450, I considered your first option, but parsing is done at the same time for both values, so this would require calling it twice. Although it gets the job done, it is weird that there isn't better.

Comment: See my answer below about secondary constructors being disfavored because they lead to less readable code. The factory approach is much better and is what I would recommend (it's what I do).

You see this in official Android code from Google very often. Lots of the components have a `companion object { fun newInstance(/* params *): ComponentInstance { /* code to generate it */ }` type code, especially for creating new view components like fragments and activities. Your code completion's going to start throwing up hard-to-use suggestions if you have a bunch of constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secondary constructors are disfavored in Kotlin. Your best solution is to use a factory method. See, e.g.:

```
class A(val a: Int, val b: Int) {
    companion object {
        fun fromString(str: String): A {
            val (foo, bar) = Pair(1, 2) // sub with your parsing stuff
            return A(foo, bar)
        }
    }
}
```

This will lead to more readable code. Imagine a class with ten different constructors identified no way other than `MyClass` as opposed to many more obvious ones enabled by the factory approach: `MyClass.fromString(str: String)` and `MyClass.fromCoordinates(coordinates: Pair<Int, Int>)` and so forth.

Secondary constructors weren't even allowed in Kotlin until relatively recently.

Answer (score 9):

You can either replace your parsing constructor with a factory method:

```
class Object(val a: Double, val b: Double) {
    companion object {
        // this method invocation looks like constructor invocation
        operator fun invoke(str: String): Object {
            // do parsing
            return Object(parsed_a, parsed_b)
        }
    }
}
```

Or make both constructors secondary:

```
class Object {
    val a: Double
    val b: Double

    constructor(a: Double, b: Double) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }

    // parsing constructor
    constructor(str: String) {
        // do parsing
        a = parsed_a
        b = parsed_b
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the latter, and it is telling me "Val cannot be reassigned" in the constructor, and "Property must be initialized or abstract" in the field definitions.

Comment: @BillThePlatypus, are you sure that you have completely removed the primary constructor, and there are no parentheses after the class name?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing after the class name

Comment: @BillThePlatypus, I am using Kotlin JVM v.1.3.61, and it [compiles and runs fine on it](https://pl.kotl.in/XidBlDSnu).