# Calling primary constructor from secondary constructor after some calculations are done

Tags: kotlin, constructor

Basic question. I have a primary and secondary constructor, and inside the secondary constructor I calculate/fetch the primary constructors

This is an issue since as far as I am aware you need to immediately call the primary constructor inside the second.

Like so

```
constructor() : this(/*parameters for primary constructor*/)
```

However, I can't call the primary constructor because I don't know the parameters yet.

```
constructor() : this(/*???*/) {
   //find parms of primary constructor
   //i want to call primary constructor here
}
```

*Is it possible to call the primary constructor later on in the secondary constructor?*

*Is there a better way to structure this to avoid the issue?*

Here is an oversimplified example

```
class Test(var name: String,var age: String,var dateOfBirth: String){
    constructor(id: String) : this(/*???*/) {
      //get name, age, dob, from id

      I want to call the primary constructor here since 
    }
}
```

My best solution was simply to send empty/null values to the primary constructor and then change them in the body of the constructor

```
constructor(id: String) : this(null,0,null) {
   name = 
   age = 
   dateOfBirth = 
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if there is a better way

It is a definite possibility there is just a far better way to structure this whole thing, that would avoid this issue altogether, so let me know if that is the case!

Comment: By definition, the code of the secondary constructor comes second. An alternative design is to have no primary constructor at all. Instead have a private final function that each of your constructors calls at some point. Might have to mark your non-nullable properties lateinit because of setting them indirectly (on phone and can’t check easily). Secondary alternative design would be to put a factory function in a companion object instead of creating a secondary constructor. And if you make the factory function an operator invoke function, it uses the same syntax as a constructor would.

Comment: There's a very similar question with good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439262/how-do-i-run-code-before-calling-the-primary-constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using any calculations inside of a constructor. This is a bad practice in general. My suggestion for you is to use builder functions. Something like:

```
class Test(
    var name: String,
    var age: String,
    var dateOfBirth: String) {
    companion object {
        fun fromId(id: Long): Test {
            //calculations
            return Test("", "", "")
        }
    }
}
```